# Excel - Where condition?

Tags: excel, count, where-clause

I have two columns with data:

```
    A         B
1   HELIOS    AU
2   HELIOS
3   HELIOS    AU
4   SPARTA
5   HELIOS    AU

Countif(A..;"HELIOS") AND Countif(B..;"AU")
```

I can count the amount of HELIOS or SPARTA in a column. But how can I count the amount of AU per HELIOS or SPARTA?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [COUNTIF**S**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx) to count with multiple criteria, e.g.

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A, "SPARTA", B:B, "AU")
```

[image]

Comment: @Jean-François: lol :) I still use office xp or 2003 too. I didn't even know that function. Time to upgrade myself even though I hate ribbon interface. Answer upvoted too :)

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at sumproduct function

http://www.meadinkent.co.uk/xlsumproduct.htm

```
=MATR.SOMMA.PRODOTTO((A1:A5="HELIOS")*(B1:B5="AU"))
=MATR.SOMMA.PRODOTTO((A1:A5="SPARTA")*(B1:B5="AU"))
```

These are the functions for my italian excel version.  :)

I think that english one is

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A5="HELIOS")*(B1:B5="AU"))
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A5="SPARTA")*(B1:B5="AU"))
```

Comment: thanks nick, but i didn't need a sum. It needed to be two criteria before it could count :)

Comment: Sumproduct returns respectively 2 and 1 like countifs() functions. Try it. :)

Comment: ooh :P i'll give it a try when I get home :)

Answer (score 3):

[DCOUNT](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dcount.php) should do what you're looking for.

It does require a label row, however, but then it allows stuff like this:
[image]